# Android VPN service Bytebuffer can't be written

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, bytebuffer

I am developing a packet sniffer Android app with VPN service but I had a trouble on read the packet from Fileinputstream to bytebuffer. The problem is that every time I write the packet to bytebuffer, it doesn't have any data inside the bytebuffer. Please give a help to me. Thanks

```
 FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(traffic_interface.getFileDescriptor());

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(traffic_interface.getFileDescriptor());
                DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();
                if (!protect(tunnel.socket())) {throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");}

                tunnel.connect((new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",0)));
                tunnel.configureBlocking(false);
                int n = 0;

                while (!Thread.interrupted()){
                    packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535);

                    int packet_length = in.read(packet.array());
                    Log.d("UDPinStream","UDP:" +packet_length);

                    if(packet_length != -1 && packet_length > 0){
                        Log.d("UDPinStream","UDP:" + packet_length);
                        Log.d("UDPinStream","packet:" + packet);

                        packet.clear();
                    }
```

The problem occupy in the following code

```
                int packet_length = in.read(packet.array());

                if(packet_length != -1 && packet_length > 0){
                    Log.d("UDPinStream","UDP:" + packet_length);
                    Log.d("UDPinStream","packet:" + packet);

                    packet.clear();
                }
```

although it successfully read the packet from the tunnel (packet_length >0), there is also no data in Bytebuffer **packet**  the pos of the bytebuffer doesn't change.
**java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65535 cap=65535]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ByteBuffers are designed to work with channels. You should use any read/write(ByteBuffer buf) interfaces of channels to get proper use of ByteBuffers.

Anyway, in your snippet, read() gets byte[], writes into it but ByteBuffer is unaware of its backed array is filled. So, you can do,

```
if (packet_length != -1 && packet_length > 0) {
    packet.position(packet_length);  // filled till that pos
    packet.flip();                   // No more writes, make it ready for reading

   // Do read from packet buffer
   // then, packet.clear() or packet.compact() to read again.
}
```

Please have a look at NIO / ByteBuffer examples before keep going.

Comment: I get it, whether the pos of the ByteBuffer will not change when writing into ByteBuffer? and I got another trouble when I writing into DatagramChannel by calling write(packet) method. I got java.io.IOException: Invalid argument error

Comment: If you call channels' write/read methods, bytebuffer's position will be changed when method returns. I am not sure how you get that exception but udp requires write buffer to be no larger than OS buffer size and max datagram size, read buffer to be at least as large as received datagram packet. So if your OS' send buffer size is 4096 and you are passing bytebuffer with size 64k, this should throw exception.

Comment: In your example, non blocking does not mean anything, so start using blocking first. Set recv buffer and send buffer sizes and try again. tunnel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF, 60000);
tunnel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_SNDBUF, 60000);

Comment: The write problem I finally solved. It seems that i forget to add datagram socket for listening the related port, and when I changed to blocking mode, the channel doesn't work anymore, I think it should use channel' send/receive method instead of read/write in blocking mode right? Now I can't read the packet data from the tunnel. I got k=0 every time in calling int k = tunnel.read(packet_received);

Comment: If you are going to use non blocking, you need Selectors to tell you channel is ready to being read. If you are using blocking, your thread waits on read call until a message received. You must use read/write (Bytebuffer b) calls of channels for either way. A blocking call on channel read wont return "0", so I guess it is still in non blocking mode.

Comment: Please find a complete code example of datagramChannel's client & server code and edit it for your purposes. There are a lot issues to handle. I would go for blocking channel code at first, Thread waits on read call, when read returns, you prepare your response and call write call, then go back to read call again.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I found a lot example of datagramChannel but most of that code are using non-blocking mode and they separated the server and client into different program. Is it a way to do it purpose on same program? also I tried blocking mode, there is still problem on read part. the thread always wait on read return but the write to tunnel is successful.

Comment: I dont understand what is the point of having client and server in the same code? If there is already a server and you r just writing client code, let it block on read call, when you recv msg it will return then you prepare your answer and write back to socket, then go to read call wait for next msg.

Comment: If you find non blocking complicated and you r willing to code server & client in the same code, use 2 threads, one for server, one for client, each thread waits on read call, when they got msg, prepare responses, writes to sock, go back and wait on read call.

Comment: Or you can use non blocking with selectors ofcourse with a single thread. Edit that example code to use same selector for both server and client sockets. I suggest using blocking mode with 2 threads though. It is simpler.